# MBR equals msdos for gparted?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr, gparted

I want to create a MBR partition table with GParted. In the confirmation window I can choose between various types of partition table. Default is `msdos`. Is it the same as MBR partition table?

I'm running GParted off Ubuntu LiveCD.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes msdos is the same as MBR so use it.

Answer (score 0):

The MBR partitioning scheme is the same regardless of OS (and should work provided your drive is < 2.2TB). FDISK as well as the other equivalents will do this for you.

If you want the partition to be "MSDOS" compatible you will need to select a FAT partition type - The highest version will depend on the version of MSDos.

For MS-DOS 2.x type 1  (FAT 12)
For MS-DOS 3.0 or greater type 6  (FAT 16)

Note that versions of MS-Dos prior to 3.3 you can only have a single partition, and before  MS-DOS 4.0 the largest partition was 32 Megs.
**If you are wanting a "Windows Compatible" type, select FAT 32 (type b).   This is probably what gparted uses.**

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. When creating a new partition table with GParted, it will ask you for the table type. Default is *MS-DOS*. OP wants to know if it's an alias to MBR partition table. (it is)

Comment: See part of my answer that I Bolded.

Comment: @davidgo: You misunderstood the question. It is not about format of individual partitions (file system) but about format of the partition table. It is usually the old "**[MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning)**" format from the time of PC DOS / MS-DOS versus the new one **[GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)** (GUID Partition Table) which is part of UEFI.

Comment: @davidgo exactly like pabouk says. Here's the [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/emVne.png).

Comment: @gronostaj Besides, you can have a fully Windows-compatible disk with NTFS partitions, no need of FAT. As for gparted, it does not use any kind of filesystem by default: after having created the MBR, it waits for the user to choose size and filesystem type for each partition.